# How to prove a binary decomposition of $x(1-x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary, brownian-bridge

Trying to find the variance of Brownian bridge (maybe not in the standard way) I settled on the formula:

$x(1-x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}2^{k-1}\left(-\frac{b_k}{2^k}+\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_i}{2^i}\right)^2$
where $x\in[0,1]$, $b_i\in\{0,1\}$

and $b_i$ are the binary representation digits of $x$ (which means that $x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_i}{2^i}$)

And I can't prove it.
I tried opening the parentheses and using the [Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Definitions) but that didn't help.

I checked the formula for many different $x\in[0,1]$ and believe it is true.

Any help is appreciated.

UPD: It can be rewritten as

$x(1-x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\left(1-2^k|x\mod{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{2^k}}|\right)^2$

without binary digits but using modulo operation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made a forehead proof.

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}2^{k-1}\left(-\frac{b_k}{2^k}+\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_i}{2^i}\right)^2 =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(b_k^2\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}2^{i-1}\right) + \sum\limits_{i<j}\left(b_ib_j\left(\frac{2}{2^{i+j}}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{i-1}2^{l-1}-\frac{2^i}{2^{i+j}}\right)\right) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(b_k^2\frac{1}{2^{2k}}(2^k-1)\right) + \sum\limits_{i<j}\left(b_ib_j\left(\frac{2}{2^{i+j}}(2^{i-1}-1)-\frac{2^i}{2^{i+j}}\right)\right) = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_k^2}{2^{2k}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_k}{2^k} - \sum\limits_{i<j}\frac{b_ib_j}{2^{i+j-1}} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_k}{2^k}\right)\left(1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{b_k}{2^k}\right) = x(1-x)$

Where the trick was to use $b_k^2 = b_k$

Comment: Very nice derivation. (+1)